# Activity calling BaseAdapter which sets OnClick() for each item in row

Tags: android, onclick, android-alertdialog, baseadapter

Without showing too much code:

I have an `Activity` "A". This `Activity` populates a `ListView` via a `BaseAdapter`,
the `BaseAdapter`'s `getView()` sets an `onClickListener()` for an item in every row.

I want to show an `AlertDialog` in `Activity` "A" when the rows' item is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you encounter problems. If you have your `BaseAdapter` version in the `Activity` A then you could simply call(in the `OnCLickListener` for that row's item that you set in the `getView` method of the `BaseAdapter`) a private method that you create in the A `Activity`:

```
private void showADialog(int position) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("The clicked row is " + position)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok?",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }

                        }).show();
    }
```

If your custom `BaseAdapter` isn't in the same file as `Activity` A then you could use the `Context` that you passed to the `BaseAdapter`(if the code for your adapter is the one from your previous question, if not you should pass it in the constructor). You could then cast that `Context` to your activity and call the previous method `showADialog()`. Also when you set the listener you should pass the `position` as a tag so you can retrieve it in the `OnCLickListener`(otherwise you could get the wrong position as the views + listener get recycled):

```
//...
item.setTag(new Integer(position)); // or if you use a ViewHolder: holder.item bla.....
item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Integer realPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
    // Here show the dialog using one of the methods above.You either:        
    // showADialog(realPosition); // when the code for your custom BaseAdapter in in the same class as Activity A
    //((CallingAlertDialogBaseAdapter) context).showADialog(realPosition); // when the code for the custom BaseAdapter is in a separate file then Activity A
    //create directly an AlertDialog. For this you'll require a valid Context(from an  Activity(getApplicationCOntext() will NOT work). 
   //You have this context from the parameter that you pass in the constructor of your custom BaseAdapter(as you ussualy pass this in the Activity where you instantiate the adapter)
   }
});
//...
```

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, it was the same code as my other post. I ended up adding `BaseAdapter` to my `History` class because `mContext` was causing a `NullPointerException` - my `DialogInterface` is in a separate class and I was trying to attach it to my `History` `Activity` class via `BaseAdapter`.